# Scope Issue (maybe): pushing to a global array from within document ready() - array returns empty outside function (server-side jQuery, Express app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, asynchronous, global-variables

Background: I'm creating a website with an HTML form where a user can input a URL, hit 'Submit,' and get taken to a new page that shows some HTML text from the URL inputted. For example, let's say a list of all headers that contain "The". Here's my code in words:

1. On pressing 'Submit', POST request to pass the URL the user inputted
2. Fetch the URL's DOM (using the Node.js jsdom library)
3. Within jQuery .ready() method, execute code to add all headers containing "The" to an array. Using a for loop, go through each header and edit some text, **then push value to a new array.**
4. Display the old and new arrays on a new page.

**It all works great until I get to the second half of #3 & #4** - *even though I'm declaring my arrays globally,* I can't figure out how to get them outside of the .ready function. When I console.log inside the .ready function just after the for loop, it logs the content (the first 2 console.log in the code below). But when I console.log outside the callback function (second 2 console.log,) both arrays print totally empty [].

All other Stack Overflow answers I found just say I need to declare them globally, but I did and still can't access the variables outside the function. Anyone have an idea?

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const request = require("request");
const fetch = require("isomorphic-fetch");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//global variable declarations
let newList = [];
let oldList = [];

//this captures the user's HTML url
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const url = req.body.url;

  //this function fetches the URL and uses the JSDOM library to get the dom
  (async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    const dom = await new JSDOM(text);
    //this requires jquery and loads the $ selector for use
    const $ = (jQuery = require("jquery")(dom.window));

    //this code selects any header containing "The" and adds to array listItems
    $(dom.window.document).ready(function () {
      let listItems = $(":header:contains(Ingredients)").get();

      //this code selects each string in listItems array, changes some text
      for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        //grab text content of each listItems array
        let currentLi = listItems[i].textContent;
        oldList.push(currentLi);
        //replace "The" with "ASDF" and add to a new array
        let newLi = currentLi.replace("The", "ASDF");
        newList.push(newLi);
      }
    console.log(oldList);
    console.log(newList);

    });
  console.log(oldList);
  console.log(newList);
  })();

  res.redirect("/results");
});
```

Comment: The 2 last console.logs are executed before the 2 firsts. Document ready is an event handler that waits for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. Possibly the res.redirect is also executed before the 2 first console.logs.

Comment: Oh right. That makes perfect sense. So to fix this, I should put the redirect inside the document ready event handler, right? Would that ensure the arrays get filled before triggering the redirect (and the following get request to /results)?